Jquery when viewport is < 768 then
I like to add script to my code but don't know how.
My code:
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 44) {
        $('body').addClass('fixed-header');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});

I need to change "44" when viewport is < 680 px to "28".

Fixed by an other way: if ($(this).scrollTop() > 28) { $('body').addClass('fixed-header-mob');

You could do something like $(this).scrollTop() > (window.screen.height < 768 ? 28 : 44); .

@fdomn-m thats not possible..
